# Como salvar uma imagem base64 no SQL e salva-la localmente como PNG

Tags: sql, sql-server, base64

Eu preciso saber se é possível salvar uma imagem base64 no SQL para depois recupera-la e salva-lá localmente como PNG ou JPEG. Eu já sei como converter para base64, mas para realizar o download em todos os browsers esta difícil por isso gostaria de saber se é possível e mais facil utilizando SQL? 
A ideia seria usar uma procedure.

Comment: Sem entender seu ambiente e caso de uso é muito complicado. No caso do SQL Server leia sobre [FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/gg471497%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Possível é, se você convertê-la para base64, pode armazenar em campos de texto que caibam o seu conteúdo.

Também é possível armazená-la em formato binário usando campos do tipo BLOB/BINARY dependendo do seu banco.

Para realizar o download você precisa revertê-la para formato binário, caso contrário o arquivo parecerá corrompido. Você pode fazer isso no próprio script responsável por disponibilizá-la para o usuário.

Agora a verdadeira questão é: porque optou por armazená-la no banco de dados, ao invés de guardá-la diretamente no sistema de arquivos?

Answer (score 0):

Bem, salvar uma imagem num banco SQL é complicado porque sua estrutura de tabelas é rígida, e, quando é feita a compressão, o tamanho varia dependendo da complexidade da imagem. Se usar um banco SQL, a melhor solução é armazenar a imagem em separado(ou talvez em algum serviço de armazenamento na nuvem) e colocar apenas o endereço desta num campo da tabela SQL.
Outra alternativa é usar um banco noSQL, como o mongoDB, no qual sua estrutura é flexível, ou seja, o tamanho do campo é definido por delimitadores, e não por alocação. Mas, é mais complicado fazer o relacionamento entre as coleções(corresponde às  tabelas no SQL), já que este não é relacional.

Answer (score 0):

Se queres mesmo efectuar esse armazenamento na tua Base de dados podes utilizar uma das duas opções:

1. Caso tenhas a certeza que a imagem não vai ter mais de 2GB armazena com Varbinary(max)
2. Caso possa acontecer esse espaço ser ultrapassado então passa a utilizar o que já mencionaram em um comentário o Filestream.

Tens aqui um link com algumas explicações:
[MSFT Sample Images](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6519.storing-images-and-photos-in-sql-server.aspx)